# How did the Supreme Court case Lochner vs. New York influence the U.S. economy?

Tags: united-states, economy, law

In 1905, the U.S. Supreme Court [ruled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lochner_v._New_York) that laws limiting the number of hours bakers could work was a violation of the [Fourteenth Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution). After this, there was a time when a series of labor laws were abolished by the Supreme Court on the same grounds (the [Lochner Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lochner_era)). From what I understand about the consequences of these decisions, the working classes were not pleased at all with the situation, but how did the Lochner vs. New York case affect the U.S. economy at the time?

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard to estimate - let alone quantify - the effects of regulation (legislation such as limiting bakers' work hours / court action striking down such legislation) on economics.

You might want to start with

1. [Lochner V. New York as Economic Theory](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=285433)
2. [Lochner v. New York: Economic Regulation on Trial](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1302207.Lochner_v_New_York)

PS. Note also [Lochnerization](https://definitions.uslegal.com/l/lochnerization/).